# Routing error in lazy loading after upgrading to Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, lazy-loading, angular8

I have upgraded to Angular 8 and found the in lazy loading modules routing. While upgrading CLI itself changed all my lazy loading routes according to new syntax.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.routing.ts 31:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (31:36)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                     title: "abc"
|                 },

> ```
>             loadChildren: () => import('./modules/abc/abc.module').then(m => m.AbcModule)
> ```
>
> |             },
>   |             {

`children: [
    {path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: InfoComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    },
    {
    path: 'abc',
    loadChildren: () => import('abc/abc.module').then((m) => m.AbcModule),
    }]`

Answer (score 1):

You could  try to remove the `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again. If this does not work, you could try to run `yarn`. This will fix the acorn package from webpack. You can also try this manually by updating to `acorn@6.1.1` using npm.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14566

Answer (score 0):

Install acorn node module to existing project.

> npm install acorn@6.1.0--save

Then try below instruction,This might solve the problem.

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. rm -f package-lock.json
3. npm install